# How accessing ref.current in an external function from a functional component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here my sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h1uaph

My console returns me

> ref.current is null

but I cant understand since I pass the ref in the function arguments. I have read I cant access ref from the render function, maybe by analogy it is the same for the returns function -here in a functional component? BUt if it is the case how can I access to the ref from a functional component?

here my snippet:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

const accessRef=(elementRef)=>{
  if(elementRef && !elementRef.current) console.log("elementRef.current is null")

}

function App() {

  let child1=React.createRef(); 

  return(
        <div 
          ref={child1}
          name="child1"
          className="circle_container pic2" 
          style={accessRef(child1)}
        >  hello world
        </div> 
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: propably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248483/react-ref-current-is-null

Answer (score 1):

```
const accessRef = async elementRef => {
  if (elementRef && !elementRef.current) {
    const foo = await elementRef;
    console.log(foo.current);
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot, do you get the following error message too: Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: ""_d" is read-only" ?

Comment: You are welcome, No I didn't get that error, what are you trying to do? @Webwoman

Comment: I have run it on stackblitz and get this error but locally is good, I just want to make some styling using the state of my react element

Comment: @Webwoman why you are styling the element by refs, you can return the new style from access Ref function! But, good if everything its working