# Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am trying to covert a small jquery component to react .but i am getting this issue **`Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`**

here is jquery simple component
http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/860LzgLL/

what component does it show "menu or tab list" .If window screen is decrease it hide menu and move to dropdown like this
[image]

I tried to implement is react .

My approach is

1. First i am calculate the width of `li`'s or sum of all width of li.
2. Also get the width of container.
3. if sum of li width is greater I `set the threshold` . render using threshold value

but when I am resize my component I am getting below error

**Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null **

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wmtunp?file=src%2FApp.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, createRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const data = [
  'Option One',
  'Option_hellodummyhhhsdshshshd',
  'Option Three',
  'Option Four',
  'Option Five'
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data);
  const [threshold, setThreshold] = useState(-1);

  const liRefs = useRef([]);
  const ulRef = useRef(null);

  liRefs.current = state.map((_, i) => liRefs.current[i] ?? createRef());

  const adjustItems = function() {
    var skipLoop = false,
      w2W = ulRef.current.offsetWidth,
      index = -1,
      totalW = 0;
    liRefs.current.map(function(li, key) {
      if (skipLoop) {
        return;
      }
      totalW += li.current.offsetWidth;
      if (totalW > w2W) {
        skipLoop = true;
        index = key;
      }
      setThreshold(index);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    adjustItems();
    window.addEventListener('resize', adjustItems);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', adjustItems);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="menu" ref={ulRef}>
        {state.map((i, index) =>
          threshold == -1 ? (
            <li ref={liRefs.current[index]} key={index}>
              {i}
            </li>
          ) : threshold !== -1 && threshold >= index ? (
            <li ref={liRefs.current[index]} key={index}>
              {i}
            </li>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )
        )}
      </ul>
      <ol>
        <li>
          Collected
          <ul id="submenu">
            {state.map((i, index) =>
              threshold !== -1 && threshold <= index ? (
                <li ref={liRefs.current[index]} key={index}>
                  {i}
                </li>
              ) : (
                <></>
              )
            )}
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My functionality break when I am resizing the window.
I am new in react js .Is there problem in my approach ?
any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248483/react-ref-current-is-null

Comment: @skrrrt is approach is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try using ? this operator, since when you are resizing it might get null or undefined based on condition but by putting this condition it will help you put an "and" check if property value exists or not.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, createRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const data = [
  'Option One',
  'Option_hellodummyhhhsdshshshd',
  'Option Three',
  'Option Four',
  'Option Five'
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data);
  const [threshold, setThreshold] = useState(-1);

  const liRefs = useRef([]);
  const ulRef = useRef(null);

  liRefs.current = state.map((_, i) => liRefs.current[i] ?? createRef());

  const adjustItems = function() {
    let skipLoop = false,
      w2W = ulRef.current.offsetWidth,
      totalW = 0;
    liRefs.current.map((li, key) => {
      if (skipLoop) {
        return;
      }
      totalW += li?.current?.offsetWidth;
      if (totalW > w2W) {
        skipLoop = true;
        setThreshold(key);
      } else {
        setThreshold(liRefs.current.length);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    adjustItems();
    window.addEventListener('resize', adjustItems);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', adjustItems);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="menu" ref={ulRef}>
        {state.map((i, index) =>
          threshold == -1 ? (
            <li ref={liRefs.current[index]} key={index}>
              {i}
            </li>
          ) : threshold !== -1 && threshold > index ? (
            <li ref={liRefs.current[index]} key={index}>
              {i}
            </li>
          ) : (
            <></>
          )
        )}
      </ul>
      <ol>
        <li>
          Collected
          <ul id="submenu">
            {state.map((i, index) =>
              threshold !== -1 && threshold <= index ? (
                <li ref={liRefs.current[index]} key={index}>
                  {i}
                </li>
              ) : (
                <></>
              )
            )}
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can reference it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: actually bug is resolve but not working as expected as jsfiddle .is my approach correct ?

Comment: Could you please help me out with your exact problem statement like what exactly you are trying to build?

Comment: I am trying to implement this http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/860LzgLL/ in react js

Comment: In other words show all `li`s if space  is available .else move to dropdown or  below more link

Comment: actually when I am resizing my window my `menu` options are not going below `more option` or dropdown

Comment: I have updated the code, just updated the adjustItems function where you are setting the threshold value. Added an else condition to that with certain modification.